# How to pass parameters to generic handlers through jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, .net-4.0

How to pass parameters to generic handlers through jquery ajax call and the return type must in json format?

I'm using this to call a method with no input parameters. How do I change it?

```
 $.ajax
            ({

                type: "Get",
                url: "../DataPoint.ashx",
                data: "MethodName=GetPoint",
                success: function (msg) {

                    n = msg;

                }
            });
```

Comment: If the data param is your problem, maybe the syntax you're looking for is: `data:{MethodName:'GetPoint'}` as the data param. Just pass a map of keys/values, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestarnd very well your question but this is one way to push arguments to the server function that returns a json string...

```
inputData={
    MethodName:"GetPoint",
    arg1:val1,
    arg2:val2,
    argN:valN
};

function success(outputData){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(outputData);
}

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "../DataPoint.ashx",
  data: inputData,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like in the code sample below (passing parameters)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: PagePath + '/' + functionName,
    data: '{"sentData":' + JSON.stringify(parameterArray) + '}',   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(msg.d);           
    },
    error: onFail
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could never get the arguments to pass so I resorted to passing them in the headers and parse them out in the handler.

```
var args = Arg1 + "," + Arg2 + "," + Arg3;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: PagePath + '/' + functionName,
data: '{}',   
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
  "X-Custom-Arguments" : args
},
success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.d);           
},
error: onFail
});
```

Zed